# golang gofmt package rewrite wildcard

Tags: go, import, url-rewriting, gofmt

I'm trying to do a `gofmt` rewrite of all packages that start with a certain prefix. Something like:

`gofmt -r 'github.com/some/path/<wildcard> -> someotherrepo.com/some/path/<wildcard>'`

Obviously `wildcard` isn't valid syntax, just showing the concept. I've tried with a single lowercase character, but that doesn't work here.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying with `gofmt`?

Comment: `gofmt` can't do this, because the wildcard can only match expressions, not arbitrary text. You can use https://github.com/rogpeppe/govers which does precisely what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Please post as an answer and I'll accept

Comment: In this case, I'd do the rewrite with `sed`

Answer (score -2):

This is what the gofmt command page says

```
Given a file, it operates on that file; given a directory, it operates on all .go files
in that directory, recursively
```

https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/

Comment: That doesn't help at all, because the path is a syntactic construct to rewrite, not a file path to operate on.